# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error when I try to run the following code.

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.rovicorp.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/linearschedule/360861/info?locale=en-US&duration=30&inprogress=true&apikey=4tquwdg8xfcd3seay9hyfr8b");
        String text = null;

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);


            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

            Log.d(text,"In Doback");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

        return text;

    }
```

I think the error comes in the HttpGet get line.

The logs are as follows

```
09-01 12:22:42.424  10416-10457/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.rest_api, PID: 10416
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:
    http://api.rovicorp.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/linearschedule/360861/info?locale=en-US&duration=30&inprogress=true&apikey=4tquwdg8xfcd3seay9hyfr8b
            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:733)
            at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:80)
            at com.example.rest_api.MainActivity$LongRunningGetIO.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
            at com.example.rest_api.MainActivity$LongRunningGetIO.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            ... 4 more
```

Please help me to resolve the issue!!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd suggest checking if there's a space at the beginning of the URL in your code.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-Example/blob/master/src/com/example/jsonexample/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

The single-argument constructor of URI (you passed as argument to HttpGet constructor) does NOT escape illegal characters. You should use the other constructors.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with your code..
here is what i did..

```
class async extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{

    ProgressDialog pd=null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(pd!=null)pd.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet;

            httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.rovicorp.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/linearschedule/360861/info?locale=en-US&duration=30&inprogress=true&apikey=4tquwdg8xfcd3seay9hyfr8b");


                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);

                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

                Log.e("In Doback",responseBody);



        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }



}
```

and it printed the desired result in logcat.

Comment: This'll convert the whole URL to look something like this : 

http%3A%2F%2Fapi.rovicorp.com%2FTVlistings%2Fv9%2Flistings%2Flinearschedule%2F360861%2Finfo%3Flocale%3Den-US%26duration%3D30%26inprogress%3Dtrue%26apikey%3D4tquwdg8xfcd3seay9hyfr8b